# Unity3D : Raycast Issues on Android Build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm using Unity 3D for developing 3D desfense game.

I made a monster that can take agro from intruders of map, making them occupied while being vulnerable to other attacks. I wanted to make monster can be moved when it's touched once.

Process: touch the monster → touch the destination → monster moves to the destination

I wanted my monster to move through the entire map, but can take intruder's agro
only when they're on the road. I'm currently using Raycast to make this happen, and I'm stuck.

It works just fine on Unity, but when it's on a build and played on the phone, monster can't recognizes the touch or can't recognizes the point where I touched.

```
if (IsClickMonster)
            {
                if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
                {
                    Ray MoveClick = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
                    if (Physics.Raycast(MoveClick, out ClickedPosition, float.MaxValue, whatCanbeClickedOn) && ClickedPosition.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("monster") == false)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Monster is Moving!");
                        clickEffect.transform.position = new Vector3(ClickedPosition.point.x, ClickedPosition.point.y + 1.0f, ClickedPosition.point.z);
                        StopCoroutine("MonsterMove");
                        IsMoving = true;
                        StartCoroutine("MonsterMove");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        clickEffect.SetActive(false);
                        StopCoroutine("MonsterMove");
                        IsClickMonster = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
```

[image: Moving the Skull Soldier]

↑ Picture of Moving the Skull Soldier. White dot(clickEffect) is where Player touched(ClickedPosition).

```
Physics.Raycast(MoveClick, out ClickedPosition, float.MaxValue, whatCanbeClickedOn)
```

Even though I'm using the "whatCanbeClickedOn" layermask, I wonder what can I do to avoid this from happening on mobile build.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with android, when something doesnt work well in android could be either you have some error or warning on execution that did not trigger on unity just by chance or maybe the phone is not capable of handling the game like it moves too many polygons or lights and it cant handle it well then starts making odd things, try checking the warnings in unity and see if any error appears too of course, thats my best bet